# How to create GUIs (such as menuconfig) with lxdialog

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, dialog

I try to generate a menuconfig by my own with the help of lxdialog (source: [lxdialog](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kconfig/lxdialog?id=HEAD)). Unfortunately this is not so well documented as I wished for. Example:

[image: example menuconfig]

**So what I did**: I included these files (see source) into a new/empty project and did nothing else. As it seems that this is the *source* of `lxdialog` I tried a quick shot by easily importing.I need to use a GUI, which is based on `.c`since I need the return values in a `C/C++` program - that's why I can't use the much more easier to develop `dialog`. I don't want to spent too much time on programming a new GUI that's why I think `lxdialog` fits my needs.

**The error:** I get lots of errors with the message `Type XYZ could not be resolved`. I refreshed the Indexer a multiple times and I even excluded every `.c` from build, but without success. I already checked the whole library for the unresolved keywords but it seems that the places where these errors come from, is the place of the first occurrence of the keyword at all.

Some of the messages:

```
[...]
Type 'chtype' could not be resolved dialog.h
Type 'WINDOW' could not be resolved dialog.h
[...]
```

**My question is**: obviousely I'm doing something wrong. Have I included to less files into my project or am I missing system wide libraries ?

Does anyone know a tutorial to step into lxdialog or at least knows how to solve these erros?

Thanks for your support

Kind Regards

Comment: You can't just take code from one project and make a new project around it, without any dependencies. Depending on what you want to do it might suffice with plain [Dialog](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Bash_display_dialog_boxes).

Comment: Since It seems to be the "source" of `lxdialog` at least I'd like to give it a try. I need to use a GUI, which is based on `.c` since I need the return values in a `C/C++` program - I don't want to spent too much time on programming a new GUI that's why I think lxdialog fits my needs

Answer (score 0):

**I found out how to remove all the errors**: The unresolved keywords are because the curses.h is not included, at the very beginning of the `dialog.h` there's a code block, that should be edited this way:

```
#ifdef __sun__
#define CURS_MACROS
#endif
#include <curses.h>
```

Additionally, the project needs to be compiled with `curses`. If Eclipse was used, in:

```
Project Settings -> 
C/C++ Build      ->
Settings GCC     -> 
C++ Linker       -> 
Libraries
```

simply type `curses` to the `Libraries (-l)`. In a ordinary makefile this would be an `g++ [...] -lcurses`

**Anyway**:

Now, that lxdialog is ready to use I'm still looking for some documentation or tutorials.

AFAI have looked into the code it is not as generic as I wished it to be, when it comes to filling the menus with own text/entries/submenus/choices. It's pretty much focused on reading only `kconfig` files.